# Swallowing, carrying, and regurgitating objects in the stomach without an Eruv

Tags: halacha, shabbat, eating, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot

In a sickening scenario, but out of pure Halachic speculation, can one swallow toy cars (or anything not Muktzeh), walk to a neighbor's house without an Eruv on Shabbos, and then regurgitate the toy cars?

Are these objects considered part of the body?

Comment: What about if I had a delicious roast for shabbos and then walked to shul? Wouldnt that constitute an issur of carrying just as much as the toy?

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%99_%D7%97